# Oracle insert 1000 rows at a time

Tags: oracle

I would like to insert 1000 rows at a time with oracle

Example:

```
INSERT INTO MSG(AUTHOR) 
SELECT AUTHOR FROM oldDB.MSGLOG
```

This insert is taking a very long time but if I limit it with ROWNUM <= 1000 it will insert right away so I want to create an import that goes throuhg my X number of rows and inserts 1000 at at time.

Thanks

Comment: to do in one shot (don't know the anything about your env, but based on the above) try either insert /*+ append */ or create table msg as select author from oldDB.msglog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather doubtful that this will really improve performance particularly given the simplicity of the `SELECT` statement.  That must be doing either a full scan of the table or of an index on `author`.  If that scan is slow, you're much better off diagnosing the underlying problem rather than trying to work around it (for example, perhaps `oldDB.MsgLog` has a number of empty blocks below the high water mark that forces a full table scan to read many more blocks than is strictly necessary).

If you really want to write some more verbose and less efficient PL/SQL to accomplish the task, though, you certainly can

```
DECLARE
  TYPE tbl_authors IS TABLE OF msg.author%TYPE;
  l_authors tbl_authors;

  CURSOR author_cursor 
      IS SELECT author
           FROM oldDB.MsgLog;
BEGIN
  OPEN author_cursor;
  LOOP
    FETCH author_cursor
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_authors
    LIMIT 1000;

    EXIT WHEN l_authors.count = 0;

    FORALL i IN 1..l_authors.count
      INSERT INTO msg( author )
        VALUES( l_authors(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: My select statement is more complex, I just simplified. thanks

Comment: @SeanKeane - If the PL/SQL approach is faster, that strongly implies that the query plan for the `SELECT` statement is incorrect.  If the query plan is incorrect, that strongly implies that the statistics on the underlying table are incorrect.  If the statistics are incorrect, it is much more appropriate to fix the underlying statistics than to code around the problem because it will inevitably affect many different queries.